# How can I guess the name of the network interface recently started?

Tags: networking, ppp

I start my USB **3G Modem** by:

```
# wvdial
```

And then I must do, in order to **acquire internet** access:

```
# route add default ppp0
```

Note that `ppp0` is the new virtual interface name.
I would like to **automate** this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
wvdial
route add default ppp0
```

But sometimes there is some previous ppp connection established (i.e: VPN), so the correct adapter must have another number (it is created as `ppp1`, `ppp2`... etc).

How could I **guess/specify the name of the newly** created `ppp` interface?

P.S: I am sure that there should be another more practical method to establish such PPP connection. So I opened [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179028/automating-ppp-connection-adding-the-insertion-in-routing-table-of-the-new-inte) other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the system to use a specific interface name with option `unit`.

Just add `unit 1` to your pppd-options file (usually `/etc/ppp/options`).

That works if you always have only one ppp-device.